# Set Profile in mvn clean install command line?

Tags: maven

How to set Profile in `>mvn clean install -DskipTests` command ?

If I set Profile in STS or Eclipse it works. How we can do this from command line ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can engage a profile on the command line by supplying a `-P` parameter.

For example:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -PmyProfileName
```

You can also engage a profile

- Through Maven settings
- Based on environment variables
- OS settings
- Present or missing files

Plenty more details [in the Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).